# Reaplce img value in html Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying replace "src" with "exampletext "string  in html file index.html stored local with this code :

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(index.html)
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    img['src'] = 'exampletext '
```

simple html code:

```
<html>

<body>
<a href="http://simple_site"/>
<img src="http://www.samplesite.com/img1">

<a href="http://simple_site"/>
<img src="http://www.samplesite.com/picture2">

<a href="http://simple_site"/>
<img src="http://www.samplesite.com/gallery3">

</body>

</html>
```

but this code doesn't work, anyone can help? And how i can save changes to html file after this changes?

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal example of you HTML file?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? And where do you intend to "save changes"?

Comment: ok i add simple code

Comment: @kowal666, I'm still not clear on where you intend to save the changes. Back to the _same_ HTML file, or a new one? Is the file locally accessible, or are you retrieving it over something like HTTP?

Comment: Your code finds the relevant tags and replaces what you want. If you `print(img)` after `img['src']` you will see the new content. Of course this new content isn't contained in your ìndex.html` file. Do you want to save this new vesion there?

Comment: i want to save changes in thesame html file ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions

```
import re  

repl = 'source'
html = re.sub('<img\s+src\s*=', '<' + repl + ' src=', s, flags=re.I)
```

Comment: I use this code with your sugesstion
https://pastebin.com/KFhEGcge but nothing change in file.

Comment: It works for me , with the html you provided ( all 'img' tags replaced with 'source' ) .  Have you tried printing it ?

Comment: Anyway , i updated the code a bit , in case 'img' is upper case

Comment: ok it work , thanks very much , how else change the code to replace only value in src=" "

Comment: You mean the link ?  Try `'src="(.*?)"'`

Answer (score 0):

Your updated content can be printed with `print(soup.prettify("utf-8"))`
So, if you need to put it into index.html file back, just write it there:

```
updated_html = soup.prettify("utf-8")
with open('index.html', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(updated_html)
```